# Graduate School admissions

Tags: graduate-admissions

I plan on applying to graduate school at the end of the summer when the application opens. I have 4 prerequisites left to take before admission if I get accepted as I am currently in my senior year of undergraduate. If one prerequisite I need to take is retaking a class because I have C+ and need a B, will that affect my candidacy since I do plan on retaking it when I have time next spring?